# MBProgressHUD and performselector problem - iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, mbprogresshud, performselector

i wrote below code to MBProgressHUD:

```
HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:HUD];
HUD.delegate = self;
HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Loading Workbench", nil);
HUD.detailsLabelText = NSLocalizedString(@"please wait", nil);
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadWorkbench) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

and in **loadWorkbench** method i wrote the code like:

[self performSelector:@selector(CallPrivateKwikis) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

but from here **CallPrivateKwikis** is never called. i am unable to find the problem.

can any one of you please help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(CallPrivateKwikis:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

Add the colon at the end of CallPrivateKwikis.

Comment: my method syntax is like: - (void)CallPrivateKwikis, so think no need to add colon but any way i added it but no use still getting the same problem

Comment: Change the syntax to -(void) CallPrivateKwikis:(id)params.

Answer (score 0):

Use HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithview:self.view]];
insted of 
HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES]; then ur problem will be solved